# Unexpected binding in QML with Q_GADGET

Tags: qt, qml

I have a gadget:

```
class ZScoreParams
{
    Q_GADGET

    Q_PROPERTY(quint64 lag MEMBER lag);
    Q_PROPERTY(qreal threshold MEMBER threshold);
    Q_PROPERTY(qreal influence MEMBER influence);

public:

    std::size_t lag;
    double threshold;
    double influence;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ZScoreParams)
```

and a property of an object of type `QVariant`:

```
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariant zscoreParams READ zscoreParams WRITE setZscoreParams NOTIFY zscoreParamsChanged)
```

its getter returns either `QVariant{}` that is `null` in QML or `QVariant::fromValue(gadget_val)`, the setter has the same logic.

Can't figure out how do I create a dialog with three SpinBox-es for editing my ZScoreParams. What is the right way to create it?

I attempted this `ZParamsEdit.qml`:

```
GridLayout
{
    property var params

    property var refreshChart: function () {}

    signal zparamsChanged()

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        refreshChart = function ()
        {
            params.lag = lagEdit.value
            params.threshold = thresholdEdit.value
            params.influence = influenceEdit.realValue
            logTable.debug("qml", JSON.stringify(params))
            zparamsChanged()
        }
    }

    Layout.margins: 5

    columns: 2
    flow: GridLayout.LeftToRight

    Label {
        text: qsTr("Lag:")
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
    }

    SpinBox {
        id: lagEdit
        value: params.lag
        from: 100
        to: 1000000
        stepSize: 100
        editable: true
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
        onValueChanged: refreshChart()
    }

    Label {
        text: qsTr("Threshold:")
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
    }

    SpinBox {
        id: thresholdEdit
        value: params.threshold
        from: 0
        to: 100
        stepSize: 1
        editable: true
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
        onValueChanged: refreshChart()
    }

    Label {
        text: qsTr("Influence:")
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
    }

    RealEdit
    {
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft

        id: influenceEdit

        decimals: 2
        realValue: params.influence
        realFrom: 0
        realTo: 1.0
        realStepSize: 0.1
        onValueChanged: refreshChart()
    }
}
```

and then in `main.qml`:

```
Dialog
{
    id: zdlg
        ZParamsEdit
        {
            id: zedit
        }
}

            IconButton {
                icon.source: "images/analyze.svg"
                onClicked: {
                    zedit.params = market.zscoreParams 
                    zdlg.open()
                }
            }
```

and got an effect that I did not expect. Each time an edit box changes, `market.zscoreParams` property setter is called.

How to make `ZParamsEdit` store a copy of my gadget and set my property value only once (with the gadget as a whole) when 'OK' button is pressed in the dialog?

Also tried

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(market.zscoreParams))
```

but got also something unexpected.

**EDIT1:**

I probably found an ugly solution with an explicitly defined function that creates a copy of the gadget:

```
    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant cloneZScoreParams(QVariant v)
    {
        std::optional<ZScoreParams> val;

        util::FromVariant(v, val);

        return util::ToVariant(val);
    }
```

and then

```
globalSettings.cloneZScoreParams(market.zscoreParams)
```

in QML.

Is there something better in QT?

Comment: Why do you define the `refreshChart` function inside Component.onCompleted?

Comment: @JarMan `refreshChart` can be defined directly, I think.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you just need some sort of local property/properties to store the copy of your data, and then you need some function that writes those copies back to data source.

Here's how I would change your code:

```
GridLayout
{
    property var params

    // Copy the data into local properties
    property lag: params.lag
    property threshold: params.threshold
    property influence: params.influence

    // Only update the local properties when spinboxes change
    function refreshChart()
    {
        lag = lagEdit.value
        threshold = thresholdEdit.value
        influence = influenceEdit.realValue
        zparamsChanged()
    }

    // Call this when OK button is clicked
    function save()
    {
        params.lag = lag
        params.threshold = threshold
        params.influence = influence
    }

    signal zparamsChanged()

    ...

    SpinBox {
        id: lagEdit
        value: lag

        ...

        onValueChanged: refreshChart()
    }

    SpinBox {
        id: thresholdEdit
        value: threshold

        ...

        onValueChanged: refreshChart()
    }

    RealEdit
    {
        id: influenceEdit
        realValue: influence

        ...

        onValueChanged: refreshChart()
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To avoid calling setter 3 times, you can provide an invokable function in your C++ class:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void save(quint64 l, qreal t, qreal i)
{
    lag = l;
    threshold = t;
    influence = i;
}
```

Now the save() function would look like this:

```
    function save()
    {
        params.save(lag, threshold, influence)
    }
```

Comment: I need a local property of type Q_GADGET. If you set `params` in `save()` in this way, the `zscoreParams` property setter is called three times, check it by yourself with C++ code.